# IOS application sending request every 30 seconds

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nstimer

I am writing an application to send gps coordinates to a server. I need to send coordinates every 30 seconds. I am using a button to initiate that sending request but i cant get a timer or a loop process to resend the coordinates every 30 seconds as i have been asked to do. Any ideas? Posting some code to help :

```
-(IBAction)pushedGo:(id)sender
{

    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    self.receivedData = data;
    [data release];




    NSString *contentType = @"text/html";
    NSString *mimeType = @"text/xml";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://telesto.zapto.org:81/SMART_EdgeNode/EdgeNode/DataFeeds/3/addMeasurement"]];





    NSString *string1 = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationController.dblLatitude];
    NSString *string2 = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationController.dblLongitude];

    NSLog(@"%@",string1);
    NSLog(@"%@",string2);

    NSString *bodystring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"geoX#%@#geoY#%@", string1, string2];

    NSData *body = [bodystring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",bodystring);





    NSMutableDictionary* headers = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [headers setValue:contentType forKey:@"Content-Type"];
    [headers setValue:mimeType forKey:@"Accept"];
    [headers setValue:@"no-cache" forKey:@"Cache-Control"];
    [headers setValue:@"no-cache" forKey:@"Pragma"];
    [headers setValue:@"close" forKey:@"Connection"];






    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];


    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    self.conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 }
```

That's the code i am using to initiate request by hitting a button on my app. Is it possible after hitting that button to make it not send just 1 request but sending many requests every 30 seconds till i exit the app or i hit another button to stop the request sending?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSTimer` :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(request:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Where i am supposed to apply that? Cause if i apply that at the start of my button code it doesnt work or it doesnt send requests every 30 seconds...

Comment: If i apply : [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(request:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  at the start of my code or after self.conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; i dont get the repeat :<

Comment: I may have missed something here, but isn't `request` a `NSMutableURLRequest`? Why are you calling it in your timer? You should place the code in your `pushedGo` function into a new function, call it `requestIt`. Then in your `pushedGo` function you would call `requestIt` and then start an `NSTimer` on repeat, calling the `requestIt` function (`@selector(requestIt)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I knew i had to use NSTimer but sooper comments kinda put it together! After making a new method called requestIt and importing in there my pushedGo button's code , i just called an NSTimer inside the IBAction with the selector as sooper mentioned and everything works fine. Just one last question a detail. Both my pushedGo button ethod and my requestIt method are in my viewcontroller's implementation file. i can call requestIt in the selector field on an NSTimer but cant find the way to call it without an NSTimer . Any thougts? thanks in advance

Comment: @DimitrisKoumouras What version of XCode are you using?